# Firefox addon upload says my ID does not match regular expression but it does

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Trying to create an extension with manifest v3. Following the guide it says I need to provide a UUID in `browser_specific_settings.gecko`. I have done that here:
'

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    ...
    "icons": {
      "48": "images/icon-48.png",
      "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "7e08ead6-7844-4272-8140-4875a3b8ab5d"
        }
    },      
    "content_scripts": [ ... ]
  }
```

But get the following:

[image: invalid uuid]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your GUID in curly brackets `{` `}`, as seen in the first RegExp or documented on MDN under the [Extension ID format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_specific_settings#extension_id_format).
So the correct code would look like this:

```
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "{7e08ead6-7844-4272-8140-4875a3b8ab5d}"
        }
    }
```

Personally I would also suggest using the "email like" format, it's  friendlier and easier to associate with the extension.